# Numpy Array multi-dimension input order

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

What are the input order for a numpy multi-dimensional array?

When I use np.ones((3,2,2)) I expect 3 arrays or size 2x2 but reading on other posts (the numpy documentation wasn't clear) some claim that the first two inputs are row and column with the 3rd input being the dimension I want to span.

Basically I want to stack multiple arrays infront of each each to create a multi-dimensional tensor similar to how torch works with [Channel, Row, Columns]

Thanks

Comment: The array displays as 3 blocks of 2x2 arrays.  By default the 3 is the outer most dimension  Often images are loaded and stored as row, col,channel (`opencv`), but the names or meaning is assigned by the user or other code.  To `numpy` none of the dimensions has an inherent meaning.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/converting-an-image-to-a-torch-tensor-in-python/ talks about a (H,W,C) order at the numpy end of the torch.numpy conversion.

Comment: Further browsing shows that (c,h,w) is the `torch` order, while (h,w,c) is used by PIL and openvc.  A numpy can be either.  Changing is just a matter of doing a `transpose`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, numpy lays out an array of size (A, B, C) as A groups of BxC elements, and each of those BxC elements are B groups of C elements.  Hence x[1,1,1] will be next to x[1, 1, 2] in memory.

However you can say, `np.ones((3, 4, 5), order='F')`, which tells numpy to use Fortran onrder instead of C order.  In this case, x[1, 1, 1] will be adjacent to x[2, 1, 1] in memory.  This is not the default.

Comment: I'm don't think `order` helps here.  It looks like `torch` normally puts the channels first, while packages like `PIL` and `opencv` load and display images with channels last.  'to-fron-numpy' functions do a transpose if needed.  The 'h,w' order is true for both.